# Over Memory consumption of Weaviate

Tags: database, out-of-memory, weaviate, memory-consumption

I've been engaged in a project for the past few months, and recently, I've come across a memory consumption issue. Currently, out of my total 47 GB of memory, one Weaviate instance is utilizing 13.1 GB, which seems higher than expected.

Upon consulting the Weaviate documentation, I discovered a method to calculate memory usage. The precise formula is as follows:

Number of objects * ( (Length of single vector * Float value precision in bytes) + (MaxConnections * Memory used by each vector[no of connections]))

Using this formula:
2750000 * ((768 * 4) + (64 * 10)) = 9.50 GB

I would appreciate any insights into potential reasons for memory consumption beyond what this calculation suggests.[Docker stats usage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BFJnS.png)

Answer (score 0):

Hi! Duda from Weaviate here :)

This is the page where you probably got this information:
https://weaviate.io/developers/weaviate/concepts/resources#an-example-calculation

This is a rough estimative and it may vary with other factors, for example while indexing, it will consume more memory, or depending on some Index configurations, etc.

Also the `maxConnections` estimate doesn't account for garbage collection.

Let me know if that helps!

Comment: Hi Duda, thank you for you time.


 Could you please help me identify what are the other factors that account in memory consumption.

As you have mentioned about Garbage collection, i believe it is mentioned that is does not make the memory free immediately. Currently i am not using my weaviate instance, meaning no amount of RAM is being consumed. So does Garbage collector itself occupies some memory.

It would be great help if you could provide some greater insights.

Thanks